# Negative eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix? And/or numerical stability of GSL "eigen_symmv" algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am calculating the linearly independent modes (and their uncertainties) of a large set of correlated variables by diagonalizing their covariance matrix, $C$, using GSL's `eigen_symmv`, which finds the eigenvalues, which I use as the diagonal of $D$.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Real-Symmetric-Matrices.html

If I calculate the covariance elements over the entire data set, the algorithm is stable, and I always get positive eigenvalues in $D$.

However, I need to look at smaller sub-sets of the data set. I can apply the same method to smaller samples from the whole distribution, but as I approach the size of the slice I need to look at, I start to get more negative eigenvalues in $D$. (I also get more anomalously small eigenvalues).

I have checked that my input matrix, $C$, is always real and symmetric. And the elements of $C$ over a small subset, qualitatively, look similar to the $C$ I get when using the whole data set. I am not exceeding the range of the double data type, and there are no zero or undefined elements anywhere in the matrix.

Shouldn't I always be getting non-negative eigenvalues if $C$ is real and symmetric? Is this a math problem or a numerical problem?

Comment: Symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues which can have any sign. Matrices which are also positive definite have only positive eigenvalues. This is true in exact arithmetic. In finite precision arithmetic the situation is more complicated and you can certainly find a tiny negative eigenvalue instead of a zero or a tiny positive value.

Comment: Note: as the question is currently written you are not distinguishing between symmetric matrices and matrices which are symmetric positive definite.

Comment: All of the elements of the matrix are real, and the matrix is symmetric. As my question is regarding whether the matrix should be positive semi-definite or not, I can't assert that it is or isn't. That's what I want to check.

Comment: A sample covariance matrix is always symmetric positive semi-definite (see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52976/is-a-sample-covariance-matrix-always-symmetric-and-positive-definite).

Comment: I have tested using both means, and I get this problem with both. Using the mean over the sub-sample is correct, but I tried using the whole sample mean just to see if that would make a difference. 

I believe that I should not be getting any negative eigenvalues. But I can't find any obvious source of a numerical error.

Comment: Here http://www2.gsu.edu/~mkteer/npdmatri.html you can find multiple reasons why your matrix could be non-positive (zero eigenvalues in theory - in practice could be negative and small). I think the co-linearity between two variables could be the most plausible cause.